# Subsetting a Data Frame Based on Character Ending

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, subset

I'm a newbie to R. I've a `data.frame`. The beginning and end, respectively, look like:

[image: Beginning of data frame]
[image: End of data frame]

What I'd like to do is to subset this data frame based on the last digit(s) of the "barcode" column. The digits go from 1 to 16, so there are 16 groups. I'd like to group these 16 into 5 groups. For example, all barcodes ending in "1" and "2" would be one subset of the data frame, all barcodes ending in "3", "4" and "5" would go into another subset, and so on.

I tried this using the `which()` and `endsWith()` functions:

```
my_frame = data.frame()
character_one = as.character(1)
subset_by_group_one <- my_frame[which(endsWith(my_frame, character_one)),]
```

However, I get the following error:

`Error in endsWith(barcode_subset, character_one) :
  non-character object(s)`

It seems that based on the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/startsWith.html), the `endsWith()` function must take in a character, and not a data frame. Yet I'd like to use it -- or something like it -- on my data frame to subset it. What's the best way to do this? Is there a way to coerce a data frame to a character? Will I need to use a loop to iterate through the data frame?

Comment: 1,2 first data frame, 3,4,5 second data frame, what of the rest? Hoe do you determine? 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.15,16? How do you break that into the remaining 3 data frames?

Comment: Please provide data as plain text using _e.g._ `dput` or `head`, not images, so other users can copy/paste it.

Comment: The problem is that `my_frame` is a whole dataframe not a single column.  You probably want `endsWith(my_frame$barcode,...)`

Comment: Generally, it sounds like you'd benefit from learning some of the basics about how data frames and subsetting works in R. Here's some suggested reading: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html  And please please please don't post images of your data or code.

Comment: @Dan Hall, sorry about pasting an image & thanks for the link. I'll hopefully have time tomorrow to read through it and the comments below.

Comment: @neilfws, I've pasted a small subset of my data [here](https://pastebin.com/q0VMTvUZ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to subset the rows according to a regular expression pattern (ends with "16", which is `"16$"`.  I think the most direct way to do this is with a logical vector that is true for those rows that end in 16.  Produce the logical vector with `grepl(pattern, x)`,  where `x` is the column with the values you're interested in.  Then subset according to rows by using that logical index vector in the row position of the subset expression `my_frame[<index vector>,]`. See how the data was simulated below. `drop` is set to `FALSE` in case the rownames are actually row names and not another column (and you don't have another column).

```
my_frame[grepl("16$", my_frame$barcode),, drop = FALSE]
#                               barcode other
# GACCTAAATGCCTGT-16 GACCTAAATGCCTGT-16  blah
# GAAATTGACATGACT-16 GAAATTGACATGACT-16  blah
```

Data:

```
barcode <- replicate(32, {
  paste(sample(c("T", "A", "C", "G"), 15, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
})
barcode <- paste0(barcode, "-", 1:16)
my_frame <- data.frame(row.names = barcode, barcode = barcode, other = rep("blah", 32), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(my_frame)
#                             barcode other
# GTCCGGTGATGATAA-1 GTCCGGTGATGATAA-1  blah
# CTGCTACATATAGAA-2 CTGCTACATATAGAA-2  blah
# GTGACCGTGGTCGAA-3 GTGACCGTGGTCGAA-3  blah
# TCTAGGACGATTACT-4 TCTAGGACGATTACT-4  blah
# GAGGGAGGCGTCCAT-5 GAGGGAGGCGTCCAT-5  blah
# CAGCAGCCTCCACCG-6 CAGCAGCCTCCACCG-6  blah
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Dan Hall's example. This builds a 'splitting/grouping vector" by removing all the material up to and including the dash, converts it to numeric and then groups it with findInterval. The grouping was somewhat unclear but you can modify the second argument to findInterval to adjust::

```
 grp <- findInterval( as.numeric( gsub("^.+[-]", "", my_frame$barcode)), 
                       c(.5, 2.5, 5.5, 8.5, 12.5, 16.5)) #split boundaries
> split( my_frame, grp)
$`1`
                            barcode other
TCGCGCGTTACATGT-1 TCGCGCGTTACATGT-1  blah
GCGTGTTATCCGCCT-2 GCGTGTTATCCGCCT-2  blah
CTCCCTCTTCTGTGC-1 CTCCCTCTTCTGTGC-1  blah
TTCTTGTGCGACAAA-2 TTCTTGTGCGACAAA-2  blah

$`2`
                            barcode other
CTTACGTCGTCAGCA-3 CTTACGTCGTCAGCA-3  blah
CCCATGTGTGACTAC-4 CCCATGTGTGACTAC-4  blah
GAGCCCAGAACTGTG-5 GAGCCCAGAACTGTG-5  blah
GTTGGCGAGCAGCAT-3 GTTGGCGAGCAGCAT-3  blah
ATTTAGGGGACCCAA-4 ATTTAGGGGACCCAA-4  blah
TGGCCAATGCGTTGA-5 TGGCCAATGCGTTGA-5  blah

$`3`
                            barcode other
TCCGTCCGGGGAGGA-6 TCCGTCCGGGGAGGA-6  blah
TTCAAATCGTCTACT-7 TTCAAATCGTCTACT-7  blah
AGGTACAATCTCGCA-8 AGGTACAATCTCGCA-8  blah
CGTGACTCCAATGGT-6 CGTGACTCCAATGGT-6  blah
CCGGGGGGTTGCCCC-7 CCGGGGGGTTGCCCC-7  blah
CTTTAAGTGTGTCAG-8 CTTTAAGTGTGTCAG-8  blah

$`4`
                              barcode other
TGCTGACAGTTAGAG-9   TGCTGACAGTTAGAG-9  blah
GGAAGGTGCAGAGGC-10 GGAAGGTGCAGAGGC-10  blah
AATTTAGGGCGGCCT-11 AATTTAGGGCGGCCT-11  blah
CCATCATGCGGGACG-12 CCATCATGCGGGACG-12  blah
TCCGAATCTGAGCAA-9   TCCGAATCTGAGCAA-9  blah
TCCCACCCTTTCTCG-10 TCCCACCCTTTCTCG-10  blah
CTCCTGGTCGCCACA-11 CTCCTGGTCGCCACA-11  blah
TCCCGCAACATGTAC-12 TCCCGCAACATGTAC-12  blah

$`5`
                              barcode other
TAAGAGTGCCAGTCC-13 TAAGAGTGCCAGTCC-13  blah
ACTCCACTGCCCAAC-14 ACTCCACTGCCCAAC-14  blah
CACCGTGGGTGCACA-15 CACCGTGGGTGCACA-15  blah
TGGGTGTCTGTCATG-16 TGGGTGTCTGTCATG-16  blah
CTGACATTGGTACAC-13 CTGACATTGGTACAC-13  blah
GCGCAGGTTCGAACC-14 GCGCAGGTTCGAACC-14  blah
TTTTTTCCCCCGACC-15 TTTTTTCCCCCGACC-15  blah
CCCAGCTGCCATTGA-16 CCCAGCTGCCATTGA-16  blah
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the function you werelooking for is `base::endsWith`. It returns a vector of booleans and has the variable as the first argument.

```
df2 <- df1[endsWith(df1$z,"2"),]
#    z whatev
# 1 x2   blah
# 3 l2   blah
# 4 y2   blah
# 5 o2   blah
# 8 v2   blah
```

`dplyr::ends_with` was essentially made to be used inside `dplyr` calls, especially select, though we could make it work as well by being careful about argument order. It returns numeric values though in this case it doesn't make a difference.

```
library(dplyr)    
df2 <- df1[ends_with("2",vars=df1$z),]
#     z whatev
# 1  v2   blah
# 3  s2   blah
# 8  j2   blah
# 9  n2   blah
# 10 z2   blah
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(z = paste0(sample(letters,10),sample(1:3,10,T)),whatev="blah",stringsAsFactors=F)
#     z whatev
# 1  v2   blah
# 2  q3   blah
# 3  s2   blah
# 4  m1   blah
# 5  l1   blah
# 6  y1   blah
# 7  a1   blah
# 8  j2   blah
# 9  n2   blah
# 10 z2   blah
```

Ironically  `base::endsWith` is much better suited for `dplyr::filter` calls than `dplyr::ends_with`.

Comment: This isn't really a dplyr approach. Look at the source code and the usage examples in the help file and you'll see that `dplyr::ends_with` is written to find a column with a name that ends with a pattern. You can force it to look for rows by combining it with base subsetting, but I think it's more straightforward to use `grepl`. It works though, so upvote!

Comment: well the parameter vars exists for a reason :), and I thought I'd show OP how to make `endswith` work in this case. But yeah it's a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regular expression to extract the endings, then join with a data frame containing the group information.

Some example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(x = paste0("AAA-", 1:16))
```

Some example groups: 1-2 = 1; 3-5 = 2; 6-9 = 3; 10-14 = 4; 15-16 = 5.

Join with `df1`:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(suffix = str_match(x, "-(\\d+)$")[, 2] %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(suffix = 1:16, 
                       group = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5)))

        x suffix group
1   AAA-1      1     1
2   AAA-2      2     1
3   AAA-3      3     2
4   AAA-4      4     2
5   AAA-5      5     2
6   AAA-6      6     3
7   AAA-7      7     3
8   AAA-8      8     3
9   AAA-9      9     3
10 AAA-10     10     4
11 AAA-11     11     4
12 AAA-12     12     4
13 AAA-13     13     4
14 AAA-14     14     4
15 AAA-15     15     5
16 AAA-16     16     5
```